# How to set scss variable value conditionally depending on root selector

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I want to change value of the variables depending on selector of the body tag.

For example:

```
$body-bg: green;
$text-color: red;
$border-style: grey;

body{
  background:$body-bg;
  color: $text-color;
}
```

And if the body has class 'dark' the variable value should be changed to something like this conditionally:

```
$body-bg: black;
$text-color: white;
```

Unfortunately, there are lots of overwrites in different files. So I can't overwrite in all places. So in my scenario, the only way is to overwrite the value of variables depending on the selector.

Comment: You can't do it with Sass variables, but you can with CSS custom variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_contrast-low :     $_color-black !default;

$_contrast-high :    $_color-white !default;

// Find the best contrast color compared to a color
@function get-contrast-text($base-color) {

  $color-brightness: round((red($base-color) * 299) + (green($base-color) * 587) + (blue($base-color) * 114) / 1000);
  $light-color: round((red(#ffffff) * 299) + (green(#ffffff) * 587) + (blue(#ffffff) * 114) / 1000);

  @if abs($color-brightness) < ($light-color/2){
    @return $_contrast-high;
  }

  @return $_contrast-low;
}
```

And you can use :

```
$my-color: #fff;
.hello {
    background : $my-color;
    color:  get-contrast-text($my-color);
}
```